# Android Studio, App throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity

I am using Android Studio and trying to use `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`. Unfortunately when my main `Activity` tries to invoke `ActionBarActivity` I get an error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`

I have added proper style to both `activities`:

`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">`.

What am I missing, to have this working in Android Studio?

Comment: ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Check out my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `support` and `appcompat` libraries to `Gradle` was not enough. I also had to add those libraries to `Project structure` as dependencies. This is confusing, because code compiles, but then crashes at runtime.

Comment: There is something very strange going on here. I created a brand new project with Android Studio, and it automatically used ActionBarActivity instead of Activity, so of course it worked. I then began to compare my project with my test project line for line trying to figure out why the test project worked, but mine didn't. I couldn't find anything. I eventually copy/pasted the test project's manifest into mine (adjusting package names) and it worked for my project! But now if I undo the paste it still works!!! what?!?!

Comment: So I had a non working project, made a manifest change to make it work, then undid the manifest change and it still worked.

Comment: I really wish I knew more about Android Project configuration to help you, but I am totally lost here and only learning now..